# Have my IOTAs gone after two consecutive snapshots?

Tags: snapshot, balances

A snapshot will remove all addresses with zero balance.

If I had `1 TIOTA` yesterday, I had `1 TIOTA`.

Lets say the IF snapshots today, I have `0 IOTA` but I am in the snapshot.

Tomorrow the if the IOTA Foundation snapshots again, I have `0 IOTA` but I am not in the snapshot.

Is my IOTA lost?

Comment: Related: https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/735/283

Comment: Generate address via index and you don’t have to generate tons of addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all positive balances will keep their value after an arbitrary number of snapshots.

Your example:

- You have 1 Terraiota
- Snapshot
- Your wallet shows that you have 0 Iota *****
- Snapshot
- You login to your wallet and generate X addresses where X is the number of addresses you generated before the first Snapshot
- Now you can see your balance again and spend your Tiota

---

***** Just because your wallet shows that you have 0 Iota, doesn't mean that you really have 0 Iota. After a snapshot the wallet only displays the value of the first address. After you generate X addresses, you will see the sum of all balances from address 0 to address X. The balance of address X is never zero, even after a snapshot.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question. What do you mean by

> I am in the snapshot

and

> I am not in the snapshot

IOTA doesn‘t have such thing. You can miss out snapshots and that won‘t affect your balance. After a snapshot, all you have to do is keep generating addresses in your wallet until your balance is fully restored. Your addresses with value always exist on the tangle, it‘s only your wallet that will need the information again, after a snapshot is performed.

Comment: In https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/tree/dev/src/main/resources there is only one `snapshot.txt`. "I am in the snapshot" means I have an address with money in `snapshot.txt`. Balances of 0 on the tangle are deleted. If my address is in `snapshot.txt` and I did not attach my wallet, then my balance is 0 on the tangle and will not be in the new `snapshot.txt` and it will not be on the tangle => Lost IOTA.

Comment: I think the flaw in my thinking is, if I have an address with money, it is not deleted, and it persists on the tangle even across snapshots. When I attach addresses to the tangle I am reattaching the zero balance addresses that were deleted in the snapshot; no the address with value already in them, they were never removed.